# VBA conditional skipping statements loop

Tags: vba

Tried to look into cells in a column and then find out if the cells has 6/7 characters and if it has i.

Then copy over.

```
Sub ctest()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 5000
    With Range("AR" & i)

        If Left(.Value, 1) <> "i" Then GoTo NextIteration Else

        If Len(.Value) = 6 Then .Copy Destination:=.Offset(, 2)
        If Len(.Value) = 7 Then .Copy Destination:=.Offset(, 2)

NextIteration:
    End With

Next i
End Sub
```

But this doesn't seem to work well..
Thanks guys.

Comment: Sub ctest()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 5000
    With Range("AR" & i)
    
        If Left(.Value, 1) <> "i" Then GoTo NextIteration Else

        If Len(.Value) = 6 Then .Copy Destination:=.Offset(, 2)
        If Len(.Value) = 7 Then .Copy Destination:=.Offset(, 2)
        
NextIteration:
    End With

Next i
End Sub

Comment: Define "But this doesn't seem to work well." - does it give an error?  Does it not do what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to skip the loop, why don't use basic `if` statement

```
Sub ctest()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 5000
    With Range("AR" & i)

        If Left(.Value, 1) = "i" Then
            If Len(.Value) = 6 Then .Copy Destination:=.Offset(, 2)
            If Len(.Value) = 7 Then .Copy Destination:=.Offset(, 2)
        End If

    End With

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thats a good idea.... however,  

If Left(.Value, 1) = "i" Then

this line doesnt seem to be recognised very well. hmm the value is all blanks